# Animated background-position of tiled background-image stops when scrolling horizontally in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a repeating background-image set on the body. I'm animating it using jQuery's animate function so that the background-position-x is constantly changing. The problem is that on Chrome the background is not animated for any part of the screen to the right of the browsers viewport. In other words if you scroll right, you see a line where the background stops animating.

Example: http://proxis.us/mwo/map.php

CSS:

```
body {
  background: url('images/bg.jpg');
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('body').animate({ backgroundPosition:"(-10000px 0px)" }, 1280000, 'linear');
```

Comment: There is no way i can help you. Sorry. The example page is killing my browser.

Comment: If i am not mistaken, that's a chrome bug....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you missed to copy-paste components from your example page (witch is killing my browser).

This code is from your example page.

```
(function($){$.extend($.fx.step,{backgroundPosition:function(fx){if(fx.state===0&&typeof fx.end=='string'){var start=$.curCSS(fx.elem,'backgroundPosition');start=toArray(start);fx.start=[start[0],start[2]];var end=toArray(fx.end);fx.end=[end[0],end[2]];fx.unit=[end[1],end[3]]}var nowPosX=[];nowPosX[0]=((fx.end[0]-fx.start[0])*fx.pos)+fx.start[0]+fx.unit[0];nowPosX[1]=((fx.end[1]-fx.start[1])*fx.pos)+fx.start[1]+fx.unit[1];fx.elem.style.backgroundPosition=nowPosX[0]+' '+nowPosX[1];function toArray(strg){strg=strg.replace(/left|top/g,'0px');strg=strg.replace(/right|bottom/g,'100%');strg=strg.replace(/([0-9\.]+)(\s|\)|$)/g,"$1px$2");var res=strg.match(/(-?[0-9\.]+)(px|\%|em|pt)\s(-?[0-9\.]+)(px|\%|em|pt)/);return[parseFloat(res[1],10),res[2],parseFloat(res[3],10),res[4]]}}})})(jQuery);
```

and

```
$('body').animate({ backgroundPosition:"(-10000px 0px)" }, 1280000, 'linear');
```

Comment: Sorry about that. Turns out that I was able to get it to work when I removed that background.js jquery plugin. Well... this is embarrassing... Thanks

Comment: Just a hint, that animation was really TOO heavy for a production site.